# Octet binary format in shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell

i cut the ip add ect: 10.0.0.0/4 into octet then when i change the octet to binary, it only appear like 1010 not 00001010, how can i make the output with octet format like 00001010.
I already try

```
#!/bin/bash
y=00000000 
o="$(echo "obase=2; 10" | bc)"
echo "ibase=2;obase=2; $y+$o" | bc -l
```

But the output still 1010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could zero-pad your output with `printf`:

```
$ printf '%08d\n' $(echo "obase=2; 10" | bc)
00001010
```

Comment: so how to take that value to a variable :/ ?

Comment: With a command substitution just like in your question: `o=$(printf '%08d' $(echo "obase=2; 10" | bc))`